# manipulating data frames in Python

Tags: python

Assume I have following dataframe in Python

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| aa | 1 |
| aa | 2 |
| bb | 3 |
| bb | 4 |

How can I get the following

| colA | colB |
| --- | --- |
| aa | {1,2} |
| bb | {3,4} |

Comment: Why would you want that?  Surely the first is easier to use in data analysis.

Comment: The title is really vague. Please [edit] to set a better one. I'm thinking like, "How can I group a dataframe column into a set?" For reference see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following aggregation to group the dataframe into a set:

```py
df_agg = df.groupby('colA').agg(set).reset_index()
```

Comment: if I use agg, the colA is not showing up in the list of the dataframe

Comment: You need to reset the index after the aggregation - I edited my answer accordingly.